# download a file from a website with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, download

i am attempting to create an automation script to install and update the mine craft editor MCEDIT on windows. here is what i have so far

```
@echo off

REM finds the architecture of the windows installation.
reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set arc=32BIT || set arc=64BIT

if %arc%==32BIT GOTO 32
if %arc%==64BIT GOTO 64

REM placeholder for testing.
set version=1.5.3.0


:32
REM attepts to use bitsadmin to download file but fails.
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" https://github.com/Khroki/MCEdit-Unified/releases/download/^%version%/MCEdit.^%version%.Win.32bit.exe .\install.exe


:64
REM another attempt at bitsadmin that also fails
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "test" /download https://github.com/Khroki/MCEdit-Unified/releases/download/^%version%/MCEdit.^%version%.Win.64bit.exe .\install.exe

REM unzips the auto extractor to current location
install.exe /s /d %cd%
:end
echo end
pause
```

so the first issue i am having is that.

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" https://github.com/Khroki/MCEdit-Unified/releases/download/^%version%/MCEdit.^%version%.Win.32bit.exe .\install.exe
```

always fails, it is also depreciated and soon to be dropped from windows entirly. i am looking for a native solution that would not require a user to download anything in additon to this script to complete the task.

The second issue i am having is that i have no way to get the current version. the files are always stored at

```
https://github.com/Khroki/MCEdit-Unified/releases/download/(version_number)/mcedit.(version_number).exe
```

So i need a way to test for the newest version on the server or a way to print a text file containing the directories and do it locally.

Comment: Downloading files in pure batch without using third-party tools like wget or curl is impossible if you aren't using bitsadmin.

Comment: i see, i am open to using bitsadmin but my commands fail for some reason, can you see any reason why? i am also open to using powershell as long as it will work in windows 7-10

Comment: No idea; I use wget because it actually works. I've never gotten Bitsadmin to work, I only hear it works.

Comment: heh same. everyone says it works but have yet to see it work

Comment: I use BitsAdmin and if it fails, i use powershell to download a file, you can take a look at this code if you want and get inspired from it ==> http://pastebin.com/j0U5fDwn